# How to set content-type when doing res.send()?

Tags: express

At the end of route function, when I do something like this.

```
res.send(JSON.stringify({...}));
```

I would like the content-type of response to be set as "text/plain", but it is "text/html". Is there way to set it explicitly? I search the document but no clue yet.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

setHeader before sending: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value

```
res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/plain');
res.send(JSON.stringify({...}));
```

Comment: Given that this question is tagged with `express`, it's probably better to use `res.type('txt')`, or maybe `res.set('content-type', 'text/plain')` instead of `res.setHeader`, as the latter is technically from a different API (though express uses it internally, and thus it does still work).  This doesn't strike me as enough problem to warrant a downvote, but I refer folks to an [answer][https://stackoverflow.com/a/61555719/313756] I just wrote for a a more thorough (and express-oriented) treatment.

Comment: This solution appears to be outdated. There is no setHeader. Just "set":
http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set

Comment: @AndroidDev as the previous comment noted, setHeader is on the node api. https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value

Answer (score 40):

There are a few ways to achieve this, the cleanest/simplest of which is probably (assuming the use of [express](https://expressjs.com/), based on the tag; see final answer option if not using expressjs):

```
res.type('txt');
res.send(JSON.stringify({...}));
```

That's using [`res.type`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.type), which gives a number of shorthands, as well as being able to set explicit mime types, e.g. (among many others):

```
res.type('.html')            // => 'text/html'
res.type('html')             // => 'text/html'
res.type('json')             // => 'application/json'
res.type('application/json') // => 'application/json'
res.type('png')              // => 'image/png'
res.type('mp3')              // => 'audio/mp3'
```

As of this writing, this is [implemented](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/1b48a5cc3cdc6ee465991952990e14985cbfc042/lib/response.js#L594) in terms of [`res.set`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set), which could also be called directly:

```
res.set('content-type', 'text/plain');
res.send(JSON.stringify({...}));
```

These are the officially documented ways of performing this functionality (except that also `res.header` is an alias for `res.set`).  However, it appears that the response objects are derived from [`http.ServerResponse`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse), and thus also have (and [use](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/1b48a5cc3cdc6ee465991952990e14985cbfc042/lib/response.js#L771), in the implementation) the [`setHeader`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value) method from that, which has the same usage as `res.set`, without quite all of the same functionality as `res.set` (some checks aren't done, etc.)... But it does get the basic job done, and so it's entirely possible one might find code in the wild that would solve your this question's goals as (especially if it's not an express application, but using the [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) package, instead):

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
res.send(JSON.stringify({...}));
```

(As a side-note: per [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2) (formerly in [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2)), the header names are case *in*sensitive.  That said, the `Content-Type` capitalization is what's used in [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5), which defines its meaning and usage, and is what `res.type` will use.  That said, I've seen at least some examples of `res.set` being used with all-lower-case header names, so I thought I'd show that both are possible.)

Comment: Nothing of this works. Express just keeps sending `text/html` for no apparent reason whatsoever.

Comment: Well, I'm guessing there's some sort of reason, though I absolutely can believe that it may not be apparent.  That said, without knowing a whole lot more about your situation, it's difficult for me to know what to suggest.  Have you tried this in an isolated test environment?  (Like, did Express stop supporting this, or is it something else you're doing?  Narrowing that down will be helpful for troubleshooting... though you might want to ask it as its own question -- and go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ... which might even be enough to solve it!)

Answer (score 8):

You can try [`res.set`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set) to set a `Content-Type` header, like so:

```
res.set('content-type', 'text/plain');
res.send(JSON.stringify({...}));
```